# Neo4j using in ASP.NET MVC, client.QueryIndex is obsolete?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

My project includes Beer, BeerBrand node. I have one relationships IsMade. When I query all beers in graph, I used this function : client.QueryIndex("Beer", IndexFor.Node, "Name: *").ToList();. After that, visual studio warned this function is obsolete. Which function I can replace it? Thanks for reading.

Comment: When posting about Neo4jClient, remember to use the Neo4jClient tag so that we see the question.

Answer (score 3):

The obsolete warning tells you why it is obsolete, and it tells you what to use instead: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/src/1f04d16433d5d836ee29c3c0fc652808f795fe4a/Neo4jClient/IGraphClient.cs?at=default#cl-98